# How do I write a terminating series representation of $_2 F_1(p, n+1, n+2, x)$

Tags: laurent-series, hypergeometric-function

How do I find a terminating series representation of the hypergeometric function $_2 F_1(p, n+1, n+2, x)$, for real $p \in \mathbb{R}$ but $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n\geq0$?

Mathematica gives (`Hypergeometric2F1[p, 1 + n, 2 + n, x] /. n -> 0`, etc)
\begin{align}
n=0:&\qquad -\frac{(1-x)^{-p} \left((1-x)^p+x-1\right)}{(p-1) x}\\
n=1:&\qquad  \frac{2 (1-x)^{-p} \left(-p x^2+(1-x)^p+p x+x^2-1\right)}{(p-2)
   (p-1) x^2}\\
\vdots\end{align}

I am getting stuck because in principle $p$ and $n$ can all be positive, so that the standard definition

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)_k(p)_k}{{(n+2)}_k k! } x^k$$

doesn't terminate.  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $\displaystyle\;\frac{(\gamma)_k}{(\gamma+1)_k} = \frac{\gamma}{\gamma+k}\;$ and assume $p - 1 \ne 0, 1, \ldots, n$ with $x \ne 0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
{}_2F_1(p,n+1;n+2;x) 
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)_k}{(n+2)_k} \frac{(p)_k x^k}{k!}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n+k+1}\frac{(p)_k x^k}{k!} \\
&= \frac{n+1}{x^{n+1}}\int_0^x \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(p)_k z^k}{k!} \right) z^n dz\\
&= \frac{n+1}{x^{n+1}}\int_0^x \frac{z^n}{(1-z)^p} dz
= \frac{n+1}{x^{n+1}}\int_0^x \frac{(1 - (1-z))^n}{(1-z)^p} dz\\
&= \frac{n+1}{x^{n+1}}  \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \int_0^x \frac{dz}{(1-z)^{p-k}}\\
&= \frac{n+1}{x^{n+1}}  \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{p-k-1}\binom{n}{k} \left[ \frac{1}{(1-x)^{p-k-1}} - 1\right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: simple, clear, beautiful. :)